# How to create SharePoint site with some of parameters editing and to add some colums with parameters

Tags: sharepoint-online, site-creation

I need to have a component which creates a site, and after gives the some parameters to create the same columns, or the same list. How could I create this component by using SharePoint Online?

Comment: Doesn't sound like a simple task. You should create the columns (and possible content types) you require at the root of your site collection to have them available at the below levels. It depends a bit on your requirement - how much "freely choosable content" you would need to have? If the set is limited, I would go with different site templates.

Comment: And how to Create different Site Template ?

Comment: Refer to the Microsoft's material for "Create and use site templates": https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Create-and-use-site-templates-60371b0f-00e0-4c49-a844-34759ebdd989

Comment: But how to add or edit Parameters ?

Comment: If you have different site templates, they would become available when normally creating a site. Then there wouldn't be any need to do a "questionnaire to find out what is needed". I'm not exactly sure if that's what you are after, parameters isn't really a SharePoint-term in this context so I might be misunderstanding something.

Answer (score 0):

See all the resources at https://dev.office.com/patterns-and-practices

Must See:

- https://channel9.msdn.com/blogs/OfficeDevPnP/Getting-Started-with-PnP-Provisioning-Engine
- https://channel9.msdn.com/blogs/OfficeDevPnP/Introduction-to-PnP-PowerShell-Cmdlets